# How to prove this ?

Tags: probability

I hope you are fine . I have a question in Probability theory subject :

We know that If X and Y are two random variables , we say that X and Y are equal in distribution (X =d Y) if they have the same distribution function .

My question is : How to prove this statement :
X =d Y if and only if X and Y have the same distribution
function, that is, P(X ≤ x) = P(Y ≤ x) for all x.

Comment: This is a definition (not the best there is for the concept, but...), not something one can prove.

Comment: As Did said, this is a definition: you don't have to prove anything.

Comment: It's a theorem . The prof asked us to prove it !

Comment: @Sara (one of these accounts). It appears that in order to answer this question you are going to have to provide the definitions used by your prof. (It also appears that you have created at least two accounts. The new one appears to be registered, so that's a start. You can suggest an edit to this question to provide the required information.)

Comment: Of course, if X and Y are continuous, then their densities can differ at a countably infinite number of points, as long as the set of such points has probability $0$. However, the distribution function (as a set function) will be the same.